# swaping array value with array index

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am a first-year student and new to programming. I was asked to write a function that can swap an array value with its index.
E.G if array : [4, 3, 0, 5, 1, 2] then O/P: array[4]=0, array[3]= 1 and so on..

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int swaparr(int arr, int len){
    int b[len];
    int k;
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        k=arr[i];
        b[k]=i;
    }
    return b;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[6]={4, 3, 0, 5, 1, 2};
    cout<<swaparr(arr, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int* swaparr(int, int)':
prog.cpp:9:16: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
         k=arr[i];
                ^
prog.cpp:6:9: warning: address of local variable 'b' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     int b[len];
         ^
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:17:25: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
     cout<<swaparr(arr, 6);
                         ^
prog.cpp:5:6: note: initializing argument 1 of 'int* swaparr(int, int)'
 int *swaparr(int arr, int len){
      ^
```

Please explain me the errors.
P.S I want to learn from the errors, so please suggest me what basics I am missing.

Comment: What do they want you to put in `array[0]`? The choices are `2` and `5`.

Comment: You function is `swaparr(int, int)`, but you pass an array and an `int`. That doesn't match. Likewise for `return b;` - `b`isn't an int, but several `int`s.

Comment: _`int b[len];`_ Variable length arrays aren't valid c++.

Comment: In addition to what was already said, your function returns `int`, but you try to return array of `int`s from it. Even if you changed the signature of the function to allow for that, you would be returning an address of a local variable, which will be, destroyed after leaving the body of a function, and trying to use such a pointer would result in UB.

Comment: @FrankPuffer How is `int b[len];` not a VLA?

Comment: @FrankPuffer If it is not modified, it doesn't mean `constexpr`. For example, I am using compiler that doesn't support VLAs, and I am getting the error `expected constant expression` on the line of array declaration.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Ok, removed my comments, still the array declaration should be valid in this context, at least it is supported by all compilers I know.

Comment: @FrankPuffer A number of compilers support that as a standard extension (e.g. GCC does). But it's not valid, standard conform c++ code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping. If I want to return an array from a c++ function then maybe I can return a pointer to an array by specifying function as int *swaparr(int len, int *arr[]), but then my return b  will give address of array b. What solution do you guys suggest. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Returning the address of any local variable is very dangerous. (For
   example, returning the address of the first element of array b,
   which you were trying to do)
2. Array are different from pointer, though an implicit conversion may
   be performed when you are trying assigning an array to a pointer (or
   initializing a pointer with an array). In fact, the pointer will
   store the address of the first element of the array, and the length
   of the array is lost during the conversion.
3. You can't copy construct an array with another array (something like
   int arr[10] = foo(), where foo will return an array type, not
   possible either). Or assign an array to another. But you can return
   a reference to an array, which is another story.
4. You better learn those knowledge from books, instead of reading an
   answer written by someone who are not good at English.

I have corrected your code with as less changes as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swaparr(int *arr, int len, int *output){
    int k;
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        k=arr[i];
        output[k]=i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[6]={4, 3, 0, 5, 1, 2};
    int swapped[6]={0};

    swaparr(arr,6,swapped);
    for (int i=0; i<6; ++i)
      cout << swapped[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

1. Instead of returning an array or an address, I prepare an array in
   function main, and pass it to function swaparr, and swaparr will
   write the result to this array.
2. One can't simply asks std::cout to print an array, you must print
   it one element after another.
3. When you have done printing, don't forget print an endl. (always)

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your efforts. Your code helps me to understand what mistake I was doing.